# Google Apps Script - Workbook A script onOpen to update Workbook B with email, date/ time, and Workbook A ID - Error with Method Signature Parameter

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, methods

I am the owner for all reporting google sheets in the company I work for and I would like to make a log of when (and if) people are opening these reports. The idea is that if nobody opens a report in a certain amount of time, we can archive the report and clean up our folders.

I want to put an app script on the reports we've built that upon opening the report workbook A, on our master report access workbook B, a new line is created at the top on the sheet named "Access Data" that writes the users email, date/ time, and workbook A ID.

I am getting an error "Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.setActiveSheet.
onOpen  @ Code.gs:5"

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var now = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT-5","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS");
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxx').setActiveSheet('Access Data');
  var originSSID = ss.getSheetId;

  destinationSS.insertRowAfter(1)
  destinationSS.getRange('A2').setValue(now)
  destinationSS.getRange('B2').setValue(user)
  destinationSS.getRange('C2').setValue(originSSID)
}
```

EDIT:
This code worked! I just specified which sheet to send it to.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var now = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT-5","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS");
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxx").getSheetByName("Access Data")
  var originSSID = ss.getSheetId();

  destinationSS.insertRowAfter(1)
  destinationSS.getRange('A2').setValue(now)
  destinationSS.getRange('B2').setValue(user)
  destinationSS.getRange('C2').setValue(originSSID)
}
```

What does this error mean and how can I fix it? It looks like it is having problems finding the workbook and sheet I am trying to make active so I can set the values?

First project in apps script so any advice is appreciated!

I tried different quotes on my sheet name. I expected it to find my sheet name on that workbook who's URL I provided. It continued to result in this error.

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5802.png)

Comment: When you open by Url there are not activesheets because there is no user interface.  Just specify the sheet you wish to write too.

Comment: Thank you @Cooper! So simple, yet it totally worked haha I thought that setting an active sheet = specifying but I tried the code edited into the original body and it worked. Thanks again and have a great weekend.

Comment: Hi @Cooper, would you like to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open by Url  or Id there are not activesheets because there is no user interface. Just specify the sheet you wish to write too.